# Knocking right underneath the valve cover?

Tags: engine

My engine was starting to make a loud knocking noise, so what I did, I turn the engine off, and I checked the oil, and the oil dipstick did not even register no oil at all? So I turned the engine on, and tried to hear where it was coming from? The loud knocking noise, was coming from one of the valve covers, right underneath it?

Comment: Have you filled the oil to the correct level?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah so uhhhh the way knock usually happens is from having inadequate amount of oil. Like, little to no oil in the engine. If you pulled the dipstick and there was NO OIL on it, that maeans your engine is dangerously low on oil. Therefore why youre probably hearing that knocking sound. i dont know what kind of car you have, but you need to add oil to it asap. Sometimes, its too late to save it. Once knock starts, its not gonna go away without any sort of engine teardown and rebuild.